# Would a Portland Design Works 700 x 37 fender fit a 700 x 32c tyre?

Tags: hybrid-bike, fenders

The [website](https://ridepdw.com/collections/fenders/products/full-metal-fenders-road-plus-size?variant=16047970910265) clearly says:

> The Road Plus Size Full Metal Fenders will fit road bikes with 700x30 tires maximum.

However, my experience with another mudguard brand (not sure anymore, I think SKS) was that the specifications were conservative and I could fit slightly larger tyres without an issue.

Does anybody know if PDW Full Metal Fenders 700 x 37 would fit a 700 x 32c tyre (on a Merida Speeder 200, if that matters)?

I don't have a bike shop nearby that sells these, so I can't go and check myself unfortunately.

Comment: The issue is how big your planned tires are when mounted on your rims, and including tread.  And you have to allow for some clearance (more in "rough" conditions) and allow for differences due to the way the fenders fit your particular bike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never going to work great, but whether it works at all depends on how much vertical clearance you have to work with. When you push the tire size, what happens is the fender can't wrap around the tire properly, and instead the tire wants to rub against the "gutter" or side of the fender. If you can simply gap the fender further away, you might be able to get by, but many bikes won't give you the ability to do so sufficiently.

Having this little overhang tends to result in an installation that needs readjustment all the time and wants to rub.

Also the actual inflated width of the tire is important here, especially since rim width can have a major impact.

Answer (score 0):

It should definitely fit just fine.  The current model year Speeder uses a Maxxis detonator 32c tire installed on a basic rim with a typical, albeit slightly older 17mm inner rim width.  You’ll definitely be able to make it fit and when those tires wear out, you can even go with a 35c tire, provided you stick with a pavement oriented tire-tread and the same rim-wheel.  If you upgrade wheels to something with inner rim width of 22mm or bigger, then you probably won’t be able to go with anything wider than a 32c tire.
Good luck